# Convenient way to get the first char index of a given string that caused a specific text pattern not to match in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

**Language**:

Rust

Rust regex crate: https://docs.rs/regex/1.5.4/regex/

**Use case:**

Printing friendly diagnostic message to user that inputs text that does not match an expected regex pattern
e.g.

1. if patterns are `Regex::new(r"^--(\w+)=(\w+)$").unwrap();` and `Regex = Regex::new(r"^-(\w+)$").unwrap();`
2. and user inputs "---abc"
3. user can see diagnostic like:

   ```
   "---abc"
      ^ Problem with character "-" at index 2.

      Expecting format "--key=value".
                          ^ Does not match expected format at index 2.
   ```

**Possible solution:**

Can I do something with capture groups? (They might only be relevant *if* there is a match). If no solution with capture groups, what else?

```
 // "-a[bc..]" or "--key=value"
 lazy_static! {
     static ref SHORT_OPTION_RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"^-(\w+)$").unwrap();
     static ref LONG_OPTION_RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"^--(\w+)=(\w+)$").unwrap();
}

// long option example
let caps = LONG_OPTION_RE.captures(s).ok_or(e_msg)?;
let key = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str().to_string();
let value = caps.get(2).unwrap().as_str().to_string();

if key.is_some { }
```

**Issue:**
Can't get *exact* char index that caused capture group not to match.

**Alternatives:**

- Just manually add in if/else checks for various indexes to try to catch every error scenario ("---a", "-a=b", etc) (Essentially implement mini parser that generates diagnostic message and problematic char index without using regex)

**Out of scope:**

I do not need recommendations for cli program libs/frameworks (unless you're pointing to an implementation detail within one)

Edit:
Modified question to be more generic than just regex.

Comment: How strongly do you want to keep regexes? I would try to use a parser, which you would then validate and you'll already have the information available too. If you keep trace of the position of the different characters, you'll be able to get precise information about the position of the error.

Comment: (Also be careful if you're using ASCII only or not, in UTF8 the "position" isn't as straightforward)

Comment: I suspect I'll do that.

It would also be convenient if the regex parser spit this information out since the regex parser already "knows" where the problem char index is, and I could then apply that to other use cases/patterns without implementing custom parsers every time.

Comment: "(Also be careful if you're using ASCII only or not, in UTF8 the "position" isn't as straightforward) – ShadowMitia 12 mins ago"
ok will do, thank you.

Comment: I'd say that's impossible in the general case. For example given the pattern `\w+a\w+` and the string `bcdefg`, which position should it report?

Comment: "I'd say that's impossible in the general case. For example given the pattern \w+a\w+ and the string bcdefg, which position should it report? – Jmb"
This hypothetically could report the last index, that is the moment where the regex parser "knows" the text doesn't match the pattern

Comment: `\w+a\w+` might be an extreme case for input validation where the end-user isn't helped as much, but for a pattern like `\w+a` the user would get a little cognitive help since mental-edit-distance from "bcdefg" to "bcdefga"  is so small

Comment: Author of regex crate here. You cannot get this information from the regex engine. In particular, you're making too many assumptions about how regex engines are implemented. This information simply is not available for all matching algorithms used without doing more work.

Comment: If you can afford to build a classical DFA, then you could use the regex-automata crate. Then you can write the search loop yourself (easy to do) and report the position at which you reach a dead state.

Comment: Thx @BurntSushi5. No assuming here, just posing questions to uncover more details of what is possible w/ a Regex engine crate's API. Thanks for DFA + search loop + dead state suggestion.

Comment: I was responding specifically to this comment: "be convenient if the regex parser spit this information out since the regex parser already "knows" where the problem char index is." But good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a parser like [nom](https://docs.rs/nom/6.2.1/nom).

Here is a quick and partial implementation of your use case:

```
use nom::{
    bytes::complete::tag, character::complete::alphanumeric1, combinator::map, sequence::tuple,
    IResult,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct OptPair {
    key: String,
    value: String,
}

fn parse_option(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, OptPair> {
    map(
        tuple((tag("--"), alphanumeric1, tag("="), alphanumeric1)),
        |(_, k, _, v): (&str, &str, &str, &str)| OptPair {
            key: k.to_owned(),
            value: v.to_owned(),
        },
    )(input)
}

fn test_parse(input: &str) {
    println!("TEST: input = \"{}\":", input);
    match parse_option(input) {
        Ok((_, opt_pair)) => println!("  Ok, {:?}", opt_pair),
        Err(err) => match err {
            nom::Err::Incomplete(_) => eprintln!("  Incomplete"),
            nom::Err::Error(err) => {
                let offset = err.input.as_ptr() as usize - input.as_ptr() as usize;
                eprintln!("  Error at index {}", offset);
            }
            nom::Err::Failure(_err) => println!("  Failure"),
        },
    }
}

fn main() {
    test_parse("--foo=bar");
    test_parse("---foo=bar");
    test_parse("--foo=");
    test_parse("Hello");
}
```

Output:

```
TEST: input = "--foo=bar":
  Ok, OptPair { key: "foo", value: "bar" }
TEST: input = "---foo=bar":
  Error at index 2
TEST: input = "--foo=":
  Error at index 6
TEST: input = "Hello":
  Error at index 0
```

Comment: Nice! I see nom has a built in error object that tracks the position of the error in the data, and I see how you calculated that offset with some pointer arithmetic. Awesome example for the "implement your own parser" approach. I'm curious now, maybe CaptureLocations.get will literally give me what I want: https://docs.rs/regex/1.5.4/regex/struct.CaptureLocations.html#method.get (Just put capture group around each something, and if any are None then call that out). Essentially calling out the errors in each component part of my regex pattern. (prefix)(alphanumeric)(delimiter)(alphanumeric)

Comment: Eh. Sticking with regex capture groups I still lose the exact index benefit I was seeking. That's the trade-off.

Comment: Accepted your answer because a declarative pattern-matching approach with `tag("--"), alphanumeric1, tag("="), alphanumeric1` without regex was not something I was thinking of, and it still shows a way to conveniently derive the exact error index, thanks!

Comment: I didn't use the rust regex crate, I can't help you for this part. The example I gave is a bit rough, you may need to improve it (error handling, maybe using `&str` instead of `String`s...); hope it helps, gl